# ORA-12996: cannot drop system-generated virtual column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

After marking a column as unused on my compressed and partitioned table, whenever i try to do

```
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;
```

I get the error:

> ORA-12996: cannot drop system-generated virtual column

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

> alter table t drop unused columns checkpoint 500;

Answer (score 0):

The system-generated virtual column typically supports a function-based index.

Please show us the DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL() for the table just like in this [Ask Tom example](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:623063677753).

Once the source of the column is known, dropping it may be easier (or maybe not in some unusual cases.)